# Cast a Map <Id, sObject> to Map <Id, Opportunity>

Tags: apex, map, sobject

I'm trying to implement the trigger framework outlined [here](http://chrisaldridge.com/triggers/lightweight-apex-trigger-framework/#comment-5):

The `triggerhandler` methods take lists or maps of `sObjects` as their inputs. In his example he casts `list <sObject>` as `list <Account>` by doing:

```
public void BeforeInsert(List<SObject> newItems) 
    {
        for (Account acc : (List<Account>)newItems)
```

What is the equivalent for:

```
public void AfterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newItems) {
for (opporutnity opp: (........).values()
```

Answer (score 9):

The `.values()` method will return a list of sObjects, which means that you can simply follow the same scenario and cast the list to a concrete sObject type:

`for (Opportunity opp : (List <Opportunity>)newItems.values())`

As long as all the values are of type "Opportunity" and you know that for sure.

The alternative way is to work with generic sObjects the whole time:

`for (sObject opp : newItems.values())`

Read more about [dynamic apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_dml.htm)

Comment: Actually, you can cast it only if the actual object contains a `Map<Id, Opportunity>`; if it's any other type, expect a runtime exception instead. You can't explicitly assign a `Map<Id, SObject>` to a `Map<Id, Opportunity>`, even if it's empty or only contains opportunities.

Comment: @sfdcfox should I put the assignment in a try/catch block?

Comment: @krewllobster No, just make sure you're using the right type to begin with. Normally you'll know what object you're working on. That is one of the drawbacks of accepting a generic SObject list instead of a specific subtype. Just make sure that if you're in an opportunity trigger, you don't try to cast to a list of accounts or something, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm working on an 'after update' trigger and need to compare old and new values. I'm now feeling like I need to cast the opportunity lists, then rebuild two opportunity maps? Then I can say: for(opportunity o: newopps.values) {if(o.value != oldvalues.get(o.id).value) {logic}}

Comment: @krewllobster I have found that maps are relatively expensive compared to list access, so I'd recommend using Trigger.new/Trigger.old, and iterating over the values like this: `for(Integer index = 0, size = Trigger.new.size(); index < size; index++) { Opportunity o = Trigger.old[index], n = Trigger.new[index]; if(n.value != o.value) { ... } }`.

Comment: @sfdcfox Are trigger new/trigger old lists guaranteed to be 1 to 1?

Comment: @krewllobster Yes. There are times when you need to use the maps, but comparing old records to new are not one of those times.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm not sure your first comment is always true as the following works fine:  `Product2[] products = [select Id, productCode from Product2];
map<String,Product2[]> productsByProductCode = Util.pivotSObjectsByString(Product2.ProductCode,products);` where the Util method returns a `map<String,list<Sobject>>` and has signature `SObjectField,list<SObject>`

Comment: @cropredy Yes, specifically lists of sobjects can be interchanged (`sobject[] accounts = new account[0]` and `account[] accounts = new sobject[0]` both work, as well as maps and sets), but there are limitations to this mechanism. With your example, if you pull out a list and try to upsert it (`upsert productsByProductCode.get('1234')`), you may get an exception. Apex does some "unclean" stuff with how types are assumed, so if you're not cautious, you can end up with difficult-to-debug situations.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but still pulls up as the result via a google search. So I'm going to post something I have had luck with.

If you know what sObject you are converting into, I've had success doing this:

```
objList //we'll say this is a Map<Id, sObject> where the sObject is an Opportunity
 List<Opportunity> oppList = objList.values();
```

Or looping:

```
   for(Opportunity o : objList.values())
   {
    //operations
   }
```

It's a little different than the previous answer given, so I hope someone finds it useful.

Edit: Apologies, realized this is for Map to Map. However I'll leave this because in some situations converting to a list from a Map will be beneficial as it should have already removed dups from being in a map, and then you can iterate through the list or perform DML on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a hash map using:

```
public void AfterInsert(Map<Id, SObject> newItems) {
    for (Id key: newItems.keySet())
    {
        Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)newItems.get(key);
        //do something with your opp
    }
}
```

So basically what you are doing here is:

- using the keySet() method on the Map to get an iterator (so you're looping on the keys)
- Then using that key, you get that particular SObject from your map (using the get() method)
- Then you are type casting from SObject directly to an Opportunity class

There's an example here: [Iterating over a map (Apex)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38767/iterating-over-a-map-apex)

Comment: I would specifically avoid doing this: using a map when a list would suffice would waste about 25ms per item in the list. That's a pretty stiff penalty.

Comment: Crikey. That's a heap. Poor heap.